# How to assign names to each widget generated through in a for loop Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

am pretty new in Python and I have a problem right now, the thing is am trying to make a widget Notebook for each item in list through for loop, but the problem is that I can't assign a name for each widget, I need the widget name to put different widgets within each Notebook widget.

As I said i'm a noob in python and I think the code below is a mess :), so thx for your help guys.

```
from tkinter import ttk
note = ttk.Notebook()

list=["tab1","tab2"]

def show_parent_name():
    name= button2.winfo_parent()
    print(name)

for i in (list):
        name_tab=i

        tab = ttk.Frame(note, name=name_tab)   #-----name define the widget
        note.add(tab, text=nombre_tab)   # ---text define the tab name
        note.pack()

        global button2
        button2 = Button(tab, text="print parent name",command=show_parent_name)
        button2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

note.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things: `list` is a builtin function. If you use `list` as a variable name the function will not be available to you anymore.

I'm importing tkinter as well, as objects and constants from tkinter are used.

I'm using `lambda` to write the button callback which lets me pass the tab name as an argument to the `show_parent_name` function. Then I don't need the global variable either.

I rewrote the usage of the loop variable a bit as it was more complicated than necessary.

Tkinter will create the window root (`Tk()`) automatically if you don't do that explicitly. But if you plan to do anything with the window besides containing the Notebook you should create it explicitly.

Try this code and see if it works the way you want:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

note = ttk.Notebook()
alist = ["tab1","tab2"]

def show_parent_name(name):
    print(name)

for name_tab in alist:
    tab = ttk.Frame(note, name=name_tab)   #-----name define the widget
    note.add(tab, text=name_tab)   # ---text define the tab name
    note.pack()

    button2 = Button(tab, text="print parent name",
                     command=lambda name_tab=name_tab: show_parent_name(name_tab))
    button2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

note.mainloop()
```